# Comparing a byte value with a bytea column in postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, servlets

I am using PostgreSQL as my database and java servlet to communicate with PostgreSQL. My application requires that I fetch data from database for a matching input file. All the files are stored in the database in a bytea column. This is my code:

```java
String checkdb="select * from key where certificate = '"+c+"';";
Statement stcheck=conn.createStatement(
    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
ResultSet newrs=stcheck.executeQuery(checkdb);
newrs.last();
int rowcount=newrs.getRow();
if(rowcount!=0)
throw new ArithmeticException();
```

where `certificate` is the name of the column containing the bytea data and `c` (uploaded) is a certificate in `byte[]` form. So here I am checking if the uploaded certificate is already present in the database. If it is present then I am throwing an exception.

But the problem is uploading the same certificate multiple times is not throwing an exception is working as if the two certificates are different.

Am I comparing the byte values correctly. What should I do to correct this?

**EDIT**
I tried setting the certificate column as the primary key. But still the certificate gets inserted into the database. How could this happen? The internal comparison also fails for some reason.
**EDIT**
I tried retrieving a ile and converted it to string :

```
InputStream input13 = retrs.getBinaryStream("certificate");
       ByteArrayOutputStream output13 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         byte buf[]=new byte[1024];
            int len;
    IOUtils.copy(input13, output13);
    input13.close();
    byte[] retvalue=output13.toByteArray();
    String s1=new String(retvalue);

String s2=new String(c);
System.out.println("in--------------"+s2);


System.out.println("out----------------"+s1);
```

retrs is the result set containing the just stored certificate. c is the input certificate in byte[]. The out put that I get is:

```
19:05:43,156 INFO  [STDOUT] in-------------------BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
19:05:43,156 INFO  [STDOUT] out----------------[B@17f8b39
```

Is my way of retrieving wrong. Because `[B@17f8b39` looks like a memory location or something like that.
**Answer**
As said by @jarnbjo One thing has to be kept in mind. When ever you use byte array in postgressql whether for `retieving or inserting` do it only using the `setBytes()` .Else only the memory location(hash code in java) of the byte[] gets inserted.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL is this? What is the jar file for the JDBC driver? (There can be problems using a driver for an older major version than the server.)

Comment: @kgrittn : my jar version- postgresql-8.4-703.jdbc3.jar and my postgresql version 8.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a PreparedStatement:

```
PreparedStatement pstat = conn.prepareStatement(
      "select * from key where certificate = ?");
pstat.setBytes(1, c);
ResultSet newrs = pstat.executeQuery();
```

You should of course do the same when inserting the data as well.

Comment: Definitive not. If so, you must do something else wrong in parts of the code not shown here.

Comment: I even tried setting the certificate column as the primary key. But the same file gets inserted multiple times. If I was going wrong somewhere postgres should not have stored the same file again after giving the primary key constraint.

Comment: you are absolutely right! I was not using setBytes() while inserting a new row in table. Once I did that everything(even the primary key constraint) works fine. If you can include that statement in your answer - where setBytes() has to be used for inserting a new row in the database also, I will accept your answer:)

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you are not doing the comparison correctly based on the results you are seeing. You need to do some debugging to figure out where things are going wrong. I'd suggest a simple test along the following lines:

- start with a clean database
- obtain a certificate from the client
- insert it into the database
- read it back out again immediately (it should be the only one)- compare the data you inserted with the data you read back. They should be the same. If they are not the same, figure out why
- Once that works, extend the test case to run a query like the one in your question. If that returns zero records, figure out why.

In terms of figuring out why there are differences, you may find it helpful to start wth a simple test case where you insert a simple byte array - such as one consisting of a single byte.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you generate file's checksum and store in db, and check the file content based on the checksum instead of the file's bytes

```
table key{
    id int,
    certificate blob,
    checksum varchar(32)
}
```

And use the following method to generate checksum of `byte[] buffer`

```
public String getCheckSum(byte[] buffer) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        MessageDigest complete;
        complete = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] rawCheckSum = complete.digest(buffer);
        for(byte b: rawCheckSum) {
            builder.append(Integer.toString( ( b & 0xff ) + 0x100, 16).substring( 1 ));
        }
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Finally,

```
String checkdb="select * from key where checksum = '" + getCheckSum(c) + "';";
```

**Edit:**

When insert bytes into db, you should use:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO key (certificate) VALUES (?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.setBytes(1, c);
```

Instead of

```
String query = "INSERT INTO key (certificate) VALUES ('" + c + "')";
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.execute();
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the primary key used to retrieve the the file. the problem is with retrieving the file itself. Please see the edit.

Comment: @Ashwin I believe your problem is unable to identify two identical file based on comparing `bytes` right? Then I recommend comparing file's checksum instead of comparing file `bytes`.

Comment: @ Pau Kiat Wee : yeah your answer would have helped if I was able to retrieve the file. You code will accurately identify the row in the table(unless there is a collision which is very improbable). But like I mentioned in the second edit. Retrieving that file from the result set gives an output like that of a memory location.

Comment: @Ashwin Can you use [getBytes(String columnLabel)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBytes(java.lang.String))?

Comment: I tried that. It did not work . Only then I switched to getBinaryStream().

Comment: @Ashwin What is the datatype of `certificate` in db?

Comment: The datatype of certificate in db is bytea.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10997/discussion-between-pau-kiat-wee-and-ashwin)

Comment: sorry my mistake. You are right about the setBytes(). But still one problem. Even after I set the certificate column as the primary key. The same certificate gets inserted multiple times.  Why is that so. Although the check sum idea is good. Yet I wanted to know the reason why it doesn't check for the primary key constraint.

Comment: Even the primary key constraint works fine now. The solution was to use set bytes everywhere.